# JavaScript: Calculate end date from start date and minutes

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have function that gets the total minutes from `start_date` to `end_date` using this line of code:

```
// format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss)
var start_date = '2019-04-23 20:15:00';
var end_date = '2019-04-23 20:20:00';

moment(end_date).diff(moment(start_date), 'minutes'); // result is 5
```

How can I get the `end_date` from a given `start_date` and `minutes`?

```
// format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss)
var start_date = '2019-04-23 20:15:00'; 
var minutes = 5;

// result should be '2019-04-23 20:20:00'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could calculate the resulting `end_date` string by using `.add()` to add the minutes value to a moment object, and then `.format()` to render a date string in the desired format like so:

```js
// format (YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss)
var start_date = '2019-04-23 20:15:00'; 
var minutes = 5;

// result should be '2019-04-23 20:20:00'
var end_date = moment(start_date).add(minutes, 'minutes').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

console.log(end_date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```